# How can I dispute moderators' decision to close "What C Compilers are most popular"?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, moderators

I've just asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288339/what-c-compilers-are-most-popular-in-the-industry) (the link is for 10k users) that was closed. However all I asked was a **list** and no discussions of this list nor any comparisons of compilers. Some of Stackoverflow user are very experienced and could have given this answer to me. Note that answer to such question cannot be found using Google.

How can I dispute on moderators decision?

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't good for building lists of stuff. Your question would be better suited to Reddit or Quora. Good questions for SO/SE are questions that attract fully self-contained answers, not items on a list.

Comment: @AnnaLear: you are sending me to different website? OK, I'll go there...

Comment: @Roman, we also recommend different websites to buy books or do your banking business!

Comment: @RomanB Don't get me wrong -- I'd love for you to use SO, but it's just not built to do certain types of questions. In those cases, you're better off using a site that will give you the answers you're looking for.

Comment: Also, demanding things in your question doesn't help.

Comment: @SimonSheehan I didn't want answer from newcomers. What bad in that? Listen, I'll explain you context, so you know *why* I'm asking this question. I'm going to give a lecture on C, particularly about inline functions. This feature seems to be differently implemented in different compilers. So I wanted that list, so that I could concentrated on 2-3 of them.

Comment: @RomanB. [Here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers) of C compilers. It can be Googled, and since you're gonna do a lecture on it, you could've read more on each compiler features and made your lecture even better.

Comment: @Nacereddine are you kidding? This list was referenced in my question! If you get introduction to inline for the first time in your life, would you like to hear about 20 compilers and how do they implement it? I guess no.

Comment: Here again we encounter the problem of someone who is apparently willing to spend at most 30 seconds writing the question, but hours defending it. @Roman, if you'd put as much effort into introducing your actual problem to the folks on Stack Overflow as you've now spent defending it to the folks here, it probably wouldn't have been closed.

Comment: @Shog9, I'm honest, I've tried to omit all kinds of the details and ask the bare question... not to ask it in 30 seconds. I've searched a lot before I asked. However, I can just be bad on asking. That can be true.

Comment: @Roman: if it makes you feel any better, I'm terrible at asking questions. I usually include *too much* detail. When in doubt, at least include a brief description of why you want the answer to your question - it'll at least give folks something to go on. BTW: for your purposes, you don't really need to get a list of popular compilers at all - unless your lecture is years in the future, you'll only have time for a cursory examination of GCC and maybe clang anyway... So you might as well just go with them, since they're open and fairly well documented (you still have your work cut out for you).

Comment: @Shog9 thank you for constructive answer. The point is I want to defend myself saying that I'll go into details for acc, bcc and ccc because they are the compilers you will most definitely meet... And that's why I came to asking this question at SO. Hopefully you understand my point now.

Comment: @RomanB.: It should also be noted that the closure and deletion of your question was not done by a [moderator](http://stackoverflow.com/about#moderators) but as a [collaborative maintenance](http://stackoverflow.com/about) action of the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers should provide you correct answers for the spirit of your question, but to answer your specific point -

> How can I dispute a moderators decision to close:

- First option - post here as you have done. This raises awareness and discussion ensues. If the community agrees, they can reopen a question
- Second option - chat for your particular site. Discuss your points. If the community agrees, they can reopen a question
- Third option - comment or edit your question. If the community agrees, they can reopen a question

With all of these, if the issue seems too out of order, Stack Exchange also have visibility and may step in.

Answer (score 14):

There is a notice at the bottom

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion. See the FAQ.

Polls are not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: So how do you ask this question if you would like to know the answer?

Comment: @Roman B: Ask it elsewhere, I guess - Stack Overflow isn't the right place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 14):

Ok, so everyone's telling you that lists and polls are a poor fit, and they are - but you probably want to know *why*; [Oded gave you a good place to start](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113784/811), but here are the gritty details:

Your question reads,

> ### What C compilers are most popular in the industry?
>
> I went to Wikipedia to check out the list of C compilers. It is very long and I think only some of them are really mature and used by industry. Please give a list of such compilers. Also, please give the answer only if you have enough experience. Thank you!

Last problem first: saying "only answer if you have enough experience" is worthless. What's "enough" experience? How would you know if I answer and *don't* have "enough experience"? Heck, if I jump on and say, "I've been working in this industry for 30 years and can say without a doubt that PCC is the only mature, industry-accepted compiler" - a complete fabrication btw - what grounds would you have to say I was full of crap?

This leads into the bigger problem: "industry", "mature" and "popular" are all undefined.

- *Which* industry? Desktop apps on Windows? Web apps on Unix? Games on ARM? iOS? Android? Embedded manufacturing / vehicle / communications control?
- *What* do you consider "mature"? Unchanged in 10 years? Version 6 or later? 90% spec compliant?
- *How* popular? Used by at least 10,000 people? 20% or greater market share within the industry? 20% or greater market share across all industries where C compilers are used? Responsible for at least 20% of all C-sourced binary code as measured in bytes?

And the single biggest underlying problem: **you don't tell us *why* you want to know!** Is this just idle curiosity? Or do you actually need to chose a compiler for something you're beginning work on? Because if it's the latter, we kinda need to know *what*! If you want to write the next great iOS app, learning that GCC is pervasive across all industries but VC has the edge on Windows won't do you a bit of good - there's a specific toolchain you'll want to use, and neither "popularity" nor "maturity" have much to do with why.

[In other words](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask),

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Comment: Well... I can answer to each your question. And I will. 1. Which industry? It doesn't matter, since the people I'm going to talk to are not yet in any industry. They just need to be familiar with most popular tools for now and learn special ones later. 2. Mature means it is used for (very) big projects and is stable. Isn't it the definition of mature.. 3. How popular? Here I wanted that the persons that answers gives me not the whole list (otherwise the the wikipedia list would have been an answer) but the 3-4 top items from it.

Comment: 4. Why do I want to know? I've already explained in the comments. I didn't feel that I need to put my question in this context. If you think I should have, I won't disagree.

Comment: What you've said in the comments so far is really the most important missing piece - everything else is unimportant, since you don't really need an ordered list of compilers by popularity anyway; you just need a smaller list. In fact, if you just asked, "How is function inlining commonly implemented?" (with a short description of what you planned to do with the information), you'd be good to go.

Comment: Now I'll be able to prove that I was well prepared before asking. There are a *lot* of questions that answer "How is function inlining commonly implemented?" Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229343/how-to-declare-an-inline-function-in-c99-multi-file-project Particularly at the accepted answer after *Edit:* And there are many others.. I needed to shorten the list of compilers only...

Answer (score 12):

This is the place to dispute moderator decisions.

However, the question was closed by the community, not the moderators. 5 people (non of which are moderators) thought it was not right for StackOverflow, and if you read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), you will see why.

The major problem with your question is that any answer is subjective. As such it is not a constructive question.

Answer (score 10):

> I'll explain you context, so you know why I'm asking this question. I'm going to give a lecture on C, particularly about inline functions. This feature seems to be differently implemented in different compilers.

If this is what you are interested in then ask *this* question - it's has the advantage of being specific and potentially answerable. It also won't generate a list of answers each of which is equally valid.